# How to get only month from MySQL date/time?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, date-format, datetime

In my MySQL server, I have rows that have the date of my created content.
Example: `2013-03-17 02:53:47`

For now, I am using:

```
$date = $fetch[thedaterownamegoeshere];

<?php echo $date; ?>
```

But instead of getting the full content of the date (`2013-03-17 02:53:47`), I'd like to get only the month – in this example, I wish to have the number "03" as the result. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## SUGGESTION #1

You could use the [MONTH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function

```
mysql> select MONTH(NOW());
+--------------+
| MONTH(NOW()) |
+--------------+
|            3 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> select MONTH('2013-03-17 02:53:47');
+------------------------------+
| MONTH('2013-03-17 02:53:47') |
+------------------------------+
|                            3 |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)

mysql>
```

You would have to put the MONTH function into the SQL command you are running.

## SUGGESTION #2

You could also try the [**PHP Date Function**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp)

```
$month = date("m",$date)
```

---

Also `DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%c')` to get `'3'` as result and `DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%m')` to get `'03'` as result.

Comment: Be careful of w3schools references... I got severely punished by some nazi downvoters for using them as a reference, even though the specific reference was 100% correct.  Apparently specific correctness does not matter in light of using a resource with a bad reputation (which is ridiculous if you ask me - plenty of correct examples can be found on slack sites, should these then not be referenced?) Guilt by association.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
 $date = date('M', strtotime($fetch['thedaterownamegoeshere']));
```

Comment: Why do they need `strtotime()`?